# Пустые строки с команды LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть текстовый файл внутри текстового файла очень много информации простым набором или копипастом человек долго будет мучаться. Решил воспользоваться командой LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. После выполнения команды phpmyadmin выдаёт сообщение что запрос выполнен успешно N ое количество строк успешно добвлены в базу. Но при просмотре базы обнаружил что добавлены только ID а все остальные поля пустые. 
Таблица состоит из id mfo bank_name колонок

Текстовый файл состоит из МФО и название банка . МФО и название банка разделены табуляцией. Как быть в таком случае

Текстовый файл следующего содержания

[image: файл откуда беруться данные]

а таблица выгладит вот так

[image: mysql таблица куда должны попасть данные из файла]

Сделал так

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/banks.txt' 
INTO TABLE banks 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(mfo, bank_name);
```

тут добавляется только mfo банка а самое название и адрес не попадаются в таблицу

Вот так выглядит текстовый файл 00204 ГОРОД., Название банка 00205 Город., "название банка" тут идет адресс банка 00206 город., "название банка"

после первых 5 цифр табуляция а дальше через пробелы

Comment: Три-четыре строки из файла добавьте в вопрос

Comment: ID у вас добавилось потому, что оно у вас AUTOINCREMENT да? В остальных полях NULL или пустые строки?

Comment: нет добавляются ID и mfo. Т е то что написано после МФО не добавляется. А в  поле bank_name  просто пустые строки даже не NULL

Comment: Было бы здорово, если вы добавите в ответ строку из файла со всеми кавычками, апострофами и указанием, где табуляции, а где пробелы. При загрузке очень много умолчаний и заранее не скажешь, какая именно запятая все ломает

Comment: Дурацкая идея, но попробуйте убрать `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' `, оно может сбивать все остальные настройки по умолчанию